# Caching of (fake) static content which is actually dynamic on GAE for Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In my GAE app I have the following handler in app.yaml:

```
- url: /lang/strings.js
  script: js_lang.py
```

So a call to `/lang/strings.js` will actually map to the js_lang.py request handler which populates the response as `application/javascript`. I want this response to be cached in the browser so that the request handler only gets called once in a while (for example when I "invalidate" the cache by importing `/lang/strings.js?v=xxxx` when I deploy a new version of the app.

For normal static content, there is the `default_expiration` element, which is very handy. And results in http response headers like this:

```
Expires: Fri, 01 Apr 2011 09:54:56 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
```

Ok, the question: is there an easy way for me to return headers such as this, without having to explicitly set them? Alternatively, is there a code snippet out there that accepts a few basic parameters such as "days" and produces the expected http-headers?

**Edit 12 April 2011**

I solved this very by simply setting the two headers `Expires` and `Cache-Control` like this:

```
import datetime
thirty_days_in_seconds = 4320000
expires_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
HTTP_HEADER_FORMAT = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:00 GMT"        

self.response.headers["Expires"] = expires_date.strftime(HTTP_HEADER_FORMAT)
self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public, max-age=%s" % thirty_days_in_seconds
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426103/asking-browsers-to-cache-as-aggressively-as-possible

Comment: Thanks balpha - I will probably end up setting agressive caching  headers explicitly. But posting this to see if someone has already solved this, or if there some yaml request handler setting I have overlooked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at *[Static serving](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-1-Static-serving)* blog post by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson).

There's everything you need to know about [Conditional request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and how to properly get and set the correct HTTP headers:

- Http Request header handling
  (`If-Modified-Since`,`If-None-Match`)
- Http Response headers handling
  (`Last-Modified`, `ETag`)